# How can I make my bot stay in a voice-chat until it is told to leave

Tags: discord.py

I've been trying to make my bot stay in the voice-chat even though there is nobody in it. I don't know how I could make the bot stay in there, I have looked in the docs but I didn't see anything about staying in.

Comment: Well why isn't he staying in the first place? Is he moved because of AFK or whats the reason? Please clarify!

Comment: He leaves if there is nobody in the VC

Comment: after a couple of minutes

Comment: Bots don't leave VC on their own, unless told to or moved. Is he being moved to AFK?

Comment: nope, but let me try again